# Secure communication in a web-service using PhoneGap

Tags: ajax, web-services, authentication, cordova, cross-domain

I am going to develop a PhoneGap application which is pretty simple.
I need to implement an authentication and some simple data transfer from the phone to the server and vice versa.
I prefer to use ASP.NET as a webservice and our database is MS SQL, but I am not sure what approach I should take to create a secure communication between PhoneGap App and the webservice.
The problem with a simple AJAX request is limitation in cross-domain and I’m not sure if JSONP is a good option.

I was wondering if someone can tell me what technology I should use in order to make a semi secure connection which works with PhoneGap (HTML5, JavaScript) and .NET webservice.
I understand that it’s a general question but I need to know what technology is the best in such a case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you may use rest interfaces and http authentication, it will be simple and it will help you get going.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is a good option as long as you sanitize(validate) the input you receive from your request. Furthermore its supported from jquery so you could use something like:

```
function retrieve(parameter1,parameter2, server) 
{
var url1 = 'http://' + server + '/endpoint.php?jsoncallback=?';
$.getJSON(url1,
          {
            param1: parameter1, 
            param2: parameter2, 
          },

          function(data) 
          {
              console.log('Data connection OK');
              retData = data;
          });
}
```

Regarding security, you could do this request over HTTPS.

At server side, the json reply should be wrapped in a function with the name taken from jsoncallback so you could achieve JSONP.